# Magento2: Create Multi Select UI Field on Frontend as Admin

Tags: category, frontend

How to create a multi-selector dropdown with Category on frontend side as Admin Add Product Page. 
Shown as here [screenshot](https://cdnblog.webkul.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Screenshot-18.png)

I am trying this Tutorial [Multi-selector on Frontend as admin side](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-create-multi-select-ui-field-frontend-admin/)

But is not working I don't understand how to make a multi-selector

Can anyone guide me slightly or suggest me any link?

Thanks

Comment: can you put the error you have or logs?

Comment: above solution link is not create any log .

Comment: sorry, I can't understand you... Magento has her own logs

Comment: If I were you I would look for another tutorial, if you look closely you can see a lot ot error in his code, and incomplete code and route, it seems like a troll...waste of time

Comment: Yes i closly see it has many error . I resolve all and dropdown is shown but still face some css issue you can see here https://ibb.co/gVZmF4q